# How to get changed DOM after Watir execute_script

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, watir

I am using Nokogiri to scrape the list of artist from http://www.englandgallery.com/artists.php. I need to use Watir, because the page loads artists using javascript.
My code looks like this

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)
browser.goto "http://www.englandgallery.com/artists.php"
browser.execute_script("javascript:loadContent('ALL');")
indexPage = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)
artists = indexPage.css('a.artistlink')
artists.each do |artist|
    puts artist.text
end
```

The page by default displays only contemporary artists, so you need to execute js to load all artists. I'm sure `loadContent('ALL')` gets executed and actually loads all artists to the page, but only contemporary artists are selected to `artists` array. What am I missing? Do I need to somehow reload the browser to get the current DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that after executing `javascript:loadContent('ALL');` it takes sometime until the list is actually updated. You could try `sleep` for a few seconds.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:phantomjs)
browser.goto "http://www.englandgallery.com/artists.php"
browser.execute_script("javascript:loadContent('ALL');")
sleep 5
indexPage = Nokogiri::HTML(browser.html)
artists = indexPage.css('a.artistlink')
artists.each do |artist|
    puts artist.text
end
```

Comment: Why would you need to use Nokogiri there? Using plain watir would be sufficient - `browser.a(class: "artistlink").each {|artist| puts artist.text }`